# If Else condition for temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
IF (@Track = 'SearchSelect')
BEGIN
    IF(@limitedAccess = 'true')
    BEGIN
        SELECT CusLst.CustomerId, MAX(CusCon.CustomerContactId) AS CustomerContactId
        INTO #CustomerList1 
        FROM CustomerList CusLst        
        LEFT JOIN CustomerContact CusCon ON CusLst.CustomerId = CusCon.CustomerId
        INNER JOIN CustomerUser ON CusLst.CustomerId = CustomerUser.CustomerId  
        WHERE CustomerUser.UserId = @userId
        GROUP BY CusLst.CustomerId
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT CusLst.CustomerId, MAX(CusCon.CustomerContactId) AS CustomerContactId
        INTO #CustomerList1
        FROM CustomerList CusLst        
        LEFT JOIN CustomerContact CusCon ON CusLst.CustomerId = CusCon.CustomerId
        GROUP BY CusLst.CustomerId
    END
```

This is causing an error as customerList1 already exists. What to do if I want to fill temporary table based on the condition in my stored procedure?

Comment: Why dont you declare 'customerList1' as table variable first then use it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before you start working

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..#CustomerList1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #CustomerList1
END
```

Comment: Do you put #CustomerList1 in tempdb ?

Comment: Or have you set PK ? If yes then you should TRUNCATE TABLE every time before you insert it to avoid the same data conflict in PK ?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

You probably have created your temp table either remove your create table or use

```
INSERT INTO #customerlist1(columns)
SELECT columns
FROM customerlist
```

since this

```
SELECT CusLst.CustomerId, MAX(CusCon.CustomerContactId) AS CustomerContactId
    INTO #CustomerList1 
    FROM CustomerList CusLst        
    LEFT JOIN CustomerContact CusCon ON CusLst.CustomerId = CusCon.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN CustomerUser ON CusLst.CustomerId = CustomerUser.CustomerId  
    WHERE CustomerUser.UserId = @userId
    GROUP BY CusLst.CustomerId
```

creates a new temp table that's why it throws an error.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Answer (score 0):

First check your temp table exists or not in your database.IF exists means drop your temp table and then create new one.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE xtype in ('U') AND id = 
object_id(N'tempdb..#CustomerList1') )
      DROP TABLE #CustomerList1;
```